# Calculate the integral $\int \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{1}{\log (x)}-\frac{1}{\log ^2(x)}\right)^2} \, dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I want to use the formula

$$l = \int_a^b \sqrt{1+f'(x)^2} \, dx$$

to find the length $l$ of a segment of the (real) line described by $f(x) := \frac{x}{\log x}$ over a continuous interval $x \in [a,b]$ with $1<a<b$. But I am not convinced that I have correctly calculated the improper integral

$$\int \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{1}{\log (x)}-\frac{1}{\log ^2(x)}\right)^2} \, dx$$

I used substitution (I have left out the constant of integration, since it will disappear from the definite integral):

Let $y=\frac{1}{\log (x)}-\frac{1}{\log ^2(x)}$. Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \sqrt{1+y^2} \, dy &= \frac{1}{2} \left(y \sqrt{1+y^2}+\sinh ^{-1}(y)\right)
\\&= \frac{1}{2} \left(\left(\frac{1}{\log (x)}-\frac{1}{\log ^2(x)}\right)\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{1}{\log (x)}-\frac{1}{\log ^2(x)}\right)^2}-\sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\log^2(x)}-\frac{1}{\log (x)}\right)\right)
\\&= \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{(\log (x)-1)\sqrt{1+\frac{(\log (x)-1)^2}{\log ^4(x)}}}{\log ^2(x)}-\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{1-\log (x)}{\log ^2(x)}\right)\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

(This last line is from Mathematica's `FullSimplify` function.)

From here, the definite integral is easy - but is this method valid? I worry that I have not accounted for potential problems in the expression $\, dy = \, d\left(\frac{1}{\log (x)}-\frac{1}{\log ^2(x)}\right)$.

If the method is not valid, then is the integral possible, and if so, how?

Comment: Your concern is justified. If you make a variable change you need to take that on account. That integral probably can't be calculated in terms of elementary functions.